# Terraform - Create aws_db_instance resource from snapshot if snapshot exists else create a new database if no snapshot exists.

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a aws_db_instance resource using the snapshot defined by final_snapshot_identifier in the case that the terraform script has already been run and the resource had previous existed and has been destroyed resulting in the snapshot having been created. If the snapshot does not exist (if its the first time I am running the terraform script in a new environment for example) it should just create a new database.

How would I go about this?  When I try to define a new data source for the snapshot it complains the snapshot does not exist and stops. Indeed the snapshot does not exist but I would like for the lack of a snapshot to result in a new DB being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really natively supported, but you can hack something together using the [External Data Source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html), like in this [Github issue comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16380#issuecomment-375318326) on this topic:

#### Set your final snapshot name

```
variable "final_snap" {
  default = "final_snap_name"
}
```

#### Use the external data source and the aws cli to find out if the snapshot exists

```
data "external" "snapshot_exists" {
  program = ["bash", "-c", "if [ ! -z \"$(aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-snapshot-identifier ${var.final_snap} | jq .DBSnapshots)\" ]; then echo '{\"SnapshotExists\": \"true\"}' | jq '.'; else echo '{\"SnapshotExists\": \"false\"}' | jq '.'; fi"]
}
```

#### Now use a [conditional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals) to decide whether or not to create a db

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "foo" {
  count    = "${data.external.snapshot_exists.result.SnapshotExists == "false" ? 0 : 1}"
  ...
}
```

If the previous external data source returned `false` then set count to `0`, therefore creating nothing. If not then set it to `1` so the DB is created.